# How do paddings in format string of C/C++ get stored in virtual memory of Linux?

Tags: linux, c, virtual-memory, c++, buffer

For example when we use `%64d` in `printf`, does this mean 64 bytes of data with the content of ASCII code for space gets stored in stack because of that `%64`? (to pass the parameters to `printf`)?

I'm asking this because I watched a video where the guy padded more than 100 million spaces to do a format string exploit (to then use the `%n` and so write a specific address to that location), but I don't understand how can someone use more than 100-150MB of data (spaces) on the stack without reaching outside of stack? I thought doing this in Linux would cause a segment fault?

If our program is a simple `printf` then usually how long can we go up (in Linux) until we reach the end of stack and thus causing a segment fault?

And also, wouldn't it cause problem with our program if we overwrite the contents of the beginning in the stack? I thought those were important stuff that was needed by the program, like env variables and such?

The video that I'm talking about (its at the end of the video):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1LH9D5cuK4&t=616s

also in other videos that there is no string passed to main function either, the format string that we put in is still on the stack and not on the heap(using gdb to show stack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `printf` with arguments such as `"%64d"`, and whatever integer is to be printed, padded to 64 spaces, the space taken on the stack is only the space needed for the arguments themselves: a pointer to a string (ignoring optimisation), and an integer. The arguments themselves aren’t expanded to take the padding into account — that’s `printf`’s job.

As to the expansion itself, that might happen on the stack for small enough padding sizes (this is what the GNU C library does at least; I haven’t checked whether the C standard specifies this), but for really large padding sizes such as that mentioned in your example, the expansion will happen on the heap (unless the padding size is so large that `printf` fails and returns an error with `errno` set to `EOVERFLOW`).

In the video, the format string used to write over 100M spaces is a string starting with the integer 0x08049724 followed by `"AAAABBBBCCCC%4$134513000x %4$n"` followed by however many ‘X’ characters are needed to pad the string out to 512 bytes. All that’s needed on the stack to call `printf` is the pointer to this string; because it’s read into a buffer on the stack, it also lives on the stack, but that’s not a requirement related to `printf`. The GOT isn’t overwritten by a buffer overflow, it’s written by the `%n` argument to `printf` which takes the address explicitly given to it. The author explicitly says that there are only 512 characters to play around with; he never says (or shows) that the millions of characters are written anywhere in the process’s memory.

Comment: But if you watch the video the actual string is stored on the stack as well, watch @4:58 and he  shows that the forth value on the stack is the ASCII code of first part of our format string in the printf( the guy created a python script to print the input of the function and uses pipe with that, the actual code is show  @0:40) and after that he padded millions of spaces and then used %n to write the number of spaces to an address, and all of that happened on the stack as he shows in the video

Comment: Also in another video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WvrSfcdq1I   @7:10 we can see that the format string of printf had 200*%x in it and all of them are stored on the stack as you can see in the video( he can see the values of stack by using printf because of format string exploit which leaks stack values)

Comment: In the video, the video’s author is providing the string which is stored on the stack, it’s not the result of an expansion. The string is padded because the author uses another script to generated a padded string, and provide that to `format4`.